# Pass cmd argument to running process when shutting down windows service

Tags: cmd.exe, c#, windows-services, process-monitor

I am creating a windowservice that starts a process where I pass multiple cmd arguments in the `StartInfo.Arguments`. That works fine as expected.

The problem is that when i stop the windowsservice, I need to tell the running program to shut down gracefully before the windows service stops. Because if I just kill the process the program does not save the collected data. The program that I run is the *Process Monitor* and it accepts the following command `"/terminate"`.

How can I pass the `/terminate` argument before my windows service stops?

Comment: Can't you use a batch file which first closes the running program with `start /wait`, then stops the service with [`sc stop`](https://ss64.com/nt/sc.html) command?

Comment: @AFH Thanks for the comment. Well I would like to keep all the code within the service itself. Anyway I just got punked for asking this question on a couple of other stack sites. So I guess my question is not 100% fitting for this forum, but I managed to find a solution. I needed to create a new instance of the process monitor and pass the `/Terminate` argument and with that it stoppes all process monitor instances gracefully.

Comment: @Örvar You can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution. In the `OnStop()` method in the service, I needed to create a new instance of the *Process Monitor* and pass the `/Terminate` argument:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.FileName = "\Procmon.exe" ;
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/AcceptEula /Terminate";
process.Start();
```

With that it stoppes all the *Process Monitor* instances gracefully.

Comment: What language is this code written?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT C# I have added it as a Tag.